# Remote Desktop Server: Restrict drive redirection on per user basis?

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, rds

For a Remote Desktop Server, drive redirection can be controlled via Group Policy. Unfortunately, this is a computer configuration, so it will either apply to all users or none.

Is there a workaround, if I allow drive redirection, to be able to somehow prevent certain users or groups from accessing the redirected drives? (Like blocking access to "\\tsclient*"-like paths...)